Reference request for a quote
The quote: "One scientific epoch ended and another began with James Clerk Maxwell." is attributed to Albert Einstein here but contains no source. I would be interested in knowing the source of it.

Like countless unauthentic Einstein's quotes in scientific books, this is repeated even in Google Books but without reference.

I reviewed all instances of "Maxwell", "epoch", "Epoche", and "Zeitalter" found in the collection of Einstein's papers at Princeton and was unable to find anything that (approximately) matches the supposed quote. I also cannot find any instance of the supposed quote that predates 1990. I therefore conclude that this is most likely a made-up quote. A less likely scenario is that this is a heavily paraphrased and condensed version of actual statements by Einstein.

@ACR Apparently there is even a brass plaque with this quote at the entrance to the Maxwell Museum in Edinburgh.

@njuffa, Out of curiosity, I had asked ChatGPT Pro, and it answered the same, that there is no solid reference to this quote. It just show how blindly most educated humans accept quotes from here and there.

I do not know the answer to the question at current, so this should be comment but is too long. The purpose is to suggest further avenues to explore the question of the possible authenticity of the quote.
I would suggest that at least in spirit the given quote is "Einsteinian" in that Einstein in numerous places has made this kind of an argument. I would point to numerous passages in his Ideas and Opinions, which have the content but not the wording of the quote. But particular noteworthy is his essay:

Einstein A. Maxwell's influence on the development of the conception
of physical reality. In Einstein A. Ideas and Opinions, p. 266ff.

It is apparently a reprint from a contribution to a commemorative volume on Maxwell: Thompson, J. J. (ed.) (1931) James Clerk Maxwell: A Commemoration Volume, Cambridge University Press, to which at current I do not have access.
To illustrate why I think the "quote" is Einsteinian consider the following passages from the essay:
On p. 266:

The greatest change in the axiomatic basis of physics—in other words,
of our conception of the structure of reality—since Newton laid the
foundation of theoretical physics was brought about by Faraday's and
Maxwell's work on electromagnetic phenomena. We will try in what
follows to make this clearer, keeping both earlier and later
developments in sight.

Then on page 268:

Then came the great change, which will be associated for all time with
the names of Faraday, Maxwell, and Hertz. The lion's share in this
revolution fell to Maxwell.

However other passages by Einstein repeat his view that Maxwell's work constituted a "revolution" from Newton or as in this passage a "blow" to it (p. 259):

Newton's theory of motion, considered as a program for the whole of
theoretical physics, received its first blow from Maxwell's theory of
electricity.

Einstein indeed even makes an epoch argument in his essay "The fundamentals of Theoretical Physics" (see Ideas pp. 323ff). He writes (emphasis is mine):

When we realize this, we are led to wonder why the so-called
revolutionary epochs of the science of physics have not more often and
more completely changed its foundation than has actually been the
case.

to later follow on page 326:

The great change was brought about by Faraday, Maxwell, and Hertz—as a
matter of fact half-unconsciously and against their will. All three of
them, throughout their lives, considered themselves adherents of the
mechanical theory. Hertz had found the simplest form of the equations
of the electromagnetic field, and declared that any theory leading to
these equations was Maxwellian theory. Yet toward the end of his short
life he wrote a paper in which he presented as the foundation of
physics a mechanical theory freed from the force-concept.

See also Einstein's Autobiographical Notes also contain similar arguments about the "revolution" brought by Maxwell.
There are numerous possibilities. One is that the "quote" is not Einstein's but it is a summary of Einstein's views as describe in various places including the two essays quoted above. It is not unusual that paraphrases and quotes are unclearly marked and confusable as seen in other cases. There is certainly a possible that it is a authentic quote, perhaps from a book backcover one-liner. If not authentic, it does seem to be a paraphrase summary that does not, in a substantive way, distort Einstein's expressed views.

Thank you very much for the detailed answer! This really really helps a lot, hopefully I uncover where this quote came from.
